# Intercepting config and hostname in fabric

Tags: python-3.x, fabric

When the user runs `fab --hosts my-host some-action` at the linux commandline, I'd like to do two things:

- Override the default sudo password setting.
- Possibly modify the hostnames

**Override ssh password.**
This first I can do (if I had the chance) by saying

```
config = Config(overrides={"sudo": {"password": "sudo password: "}})
```

and passing that config to the `Context` when it's created.  But my problem is that fab creates the context for me (yeah!) and I haven't found a hook to change that.

Requesting users to remember always to pass an extra flag to fabric is error-prone.  Asking users to create a config file or to install a pre-created config file is overhead I'd rather not impose.

**Modify hostname.**
FQDNs can be long, we have a culture of using shortened nicknames.  I'd like to catch the hosts the user specifies and "fix" them based on the way people here talk about hostnames.  In fabric1, I'd have done this with the `env.hosts` dict.  In fabric2, however, I again need to catch this before the `Connection` / `Context` is created.

Now in both of these cases I could do this by simply writing my own python program that does these things and then calls the appropriate tasks in my fabfile, which I'll therefore not call `fabfile.py` to avoid confusion.  But these seem common enough concerns that I suspect I've just missed something.

Any pointers?